# Is log transforming square root transformed data a legitimate data transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, dataset

Is it legitimate to do a "double transformation" on data? Specifically, log transforming data which has already been square root transformed, or conversely, square root transforming log transformed data? Does this even make sense?

Comment: It would help if you could say add something to your question about what you are trying to accomplish with the transformation. Note that taking the log of the square root of a value is just one-half the log of the original value.

Comment: You don't say what you want to do with these transformations...use them in a regression? Transformations of *any* kind do not violate any assumptions of multiple regression. In other words, you are free to do whatever you want to with your information. You may later be asked what they mean or how they "improved" the model. That would be a tougher challenge and, in some cases, sufficient cause not to use them.

Comment: I'm trying to normalize the distributions of my predictor variables (includes both count and proportion data), which are currently negatively skewed. I'm planning on doing a principal components analysis, and then using the factor scores in a GLM. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Ah! Another option is to employ a factor analytic approach that accounts for extreme valued information. See this paper on *Cauchy PCA* from some guys at CMU. It describes four different types of data and the differing assumptions that go with each. Having done it, it's not that hard to code up in Python, SAS or any other software.   http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pengtaox/papers/cpca.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Specifically, no.

Using natural logarithms for concreteness, and a generic variable $x$, the transformation $\ln \sqrt{x}$ is defined easily for positive numbers, but also can be seen to be just $\ln x^{0.5} = 0.5 \ln x$. Hence it has exactly the same effect in terms of effect on nonlinearity, asymmetry, lack of Gaussianity -- or whatever the transformation is designed to cure or improve -- as $\ln x$.

The transformation $\sqrt{\ln x}$ is defined easily for $x > 1$, but that seems also to be an artificial constraint. I'd be happy to learn of a rationale but I can't think of one. If you want a transformation that is stronger than the logarithm, the reciprocal is a simpler transformation to consider first. Reciprocals can be applied usefully so long as all values are positive or all values are negative.

Generally, there certainly are useful transformations that can be regarded as two-step functions, e.g. the logit $\ln [p / (1 - p)]$ or the angular transformation $\arcsin \sqrt{p}$. Here the domain is now proportions or probabilities $p$ and $0 < p < 1$ for logit and $0 \le p \le 1$ for angular. If a transformation is useful and natural enough, we tend to regard it as a function directly defined and named, so that (e.g.) statistical software commonly supplies logit functions for immediate use.

Some might want to underline that in some contexts complex results, i.e. those with real and imaginary parts, might be interesting or useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and excellent information. My data set includes both count and proportion variables, which are currently negatively (left) skewed. I have tried the reciprocal transformation, but it seems to have too strong an effect on my data - the distributions become extremely positively skewed. I've been looking into the arcsin transformation, but I'm a bit confused about how it is calculated. I also have some reservations about using it after finding this article: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/10-0340.1/full. I will look into trying the logit. Thanks.

Comment: Left-skewed variables will be made **worse** by taking roots or logarithms or reciprocals, even if the slgn of skewness is flipped (as reciprocals will do). Squares or cubes can help in principle; in practice I think you are likely to be overestimating the need for normal distributions. But I've a hard time imagining situations with left-skewed counts; there is likely to be some crucial context that you are not telling us about. How big is the dataset? Can you post it? Can you plot it?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I'm saying that backwards - It is right skewed! My count data are pesticide concentrations from water samples...many values are zero or very low, which is driving the skewness. I think you are probably right that I'm overestimating the need for normal distributions, particularly since I plan to do PCA (I've read normality is not required for this). However, since I then plan to use the factor/component scores in a GLM, I thought it would be best to normalize the original data first. Maybe this is unnecessary? Or perhaps just normalize the factor scores?

Comment: Concentrations can't be counts even if reported as integers by convention: the units are presumably ppm/ppb/ppt. . As before comment is difficult when you don't show or plot the data. What is crucial for  generalized linear models is how the response or outcome behaves and non-normal families can be not only allowed but also entirely natural. I'd omit the PCA and move straight towards GLM.

Comment: Data set is comprised of landscape variables (% various cover types), water quality variables (pesticides & nitrogen), and biological responses (aquatic invertebrates, and 2 biological measures of water quality) from 28 sites. Due to the large variable to sample size ratio, I though it would best to do a PCA on the predictors (many of which are correlated).

Comment: PCA has its good uses but doing your thinking about cause or process is not among them.

Comment: I could show some examples of some of the histograms - best to edit and post in the original questions? Good to know that concentrations are not counts - if not counts, what type of variable/family are they considered?

Comment: Concentrations are surely **measured** variables. If you care about nominal/interval/ordinal/ratio they are surely ratio scale. As said, if they have units of measurement, they can't be counts. I think you're morphing towards a different question. Comments are not a good medium for discussing good models for your data.

Answer (score 4):

By the properties of logarithms, $$
y = \sqrt{x}
$$$$
\log(y)=0.5\log(x)
$$

So the net effect in something like a regression setting is to add a constant multiplier out front of the variable, i.e. to double the coefficient value of the log-square-root compared to simply taking the log.

But in other contexts, the effect won't matter at all! If you're using decision tree methods (e.g. random forest), and x > 0, then it won't even matter because these models are insensitive to monotonic transformations of the data.